# How to trap click/dbl-click in a Subform whose SourceObject is a Query

Tags: forms, click, ms-access-2007, double-click, crosstab

Access 2007

Hello I'm asking the same question asked [here](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/access-l/how-to-trap-clickdblclick-in-a-subform-whose-sourceobject-is-a-query-4979791)

Form has a query sourceobject but i want to catch the click/double click event

This is a followup from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491409/ms-access-double-click-event-on-query/14503473#14503473), when i change from one field to another in the same record the field with

```
    screen.activecontrol
```

does not update accordinigly.

Best regards,

Comment: I know when this is happening, I think, but I cannot see a workaround at the moment. `screen.activecontrol` updates when you move from row to row, but not when you move along a row.

Comment: What i find is that if you change from field to field you can put F9 in the form with a query as a sourceobject and it will update the fields on the master form, it would be a manner of trapping that event somehow, you could just move diagonally but just wondering if there's something we're missing